# GoogleTest/Mock SaveArg of a rapidjson::Value&

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to use GoogleTest to get back an argument that's passed to a function. That function's declaration is like this

```
void foo(rapidjson::Value &element, int number) {}
```

I'd create an `ON_CALL` like this

```
rapidjson::Value elementVal;
ON_CALL(SomeClassNameWhereFooIsAMember, foo).WillByDefault(SaveArg<0>(&elementVal));
```

I can't even compile this.

```
error C2248: 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>,rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>>::GenericValue': cannot access private member declared in class 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>,rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>>'
```

Any ideas?

### Update1:

I tried the following as per Chris Olsen's response

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

using namespace ::testing;

class FooClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo(rapidjson::Value& element, int number) {}
};

class MockFoo : public FooClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, foo, (rapidjson::Value& element, int number));
};

ACTION_P(SaveRapidJsonValueArg, p)
{
    rapidjson::Document d;  // Needed only to get the required allocator param
    p->CopyFrom(arg0, d.GetAllocator());
}

TEST(RapidJsonTests, SaveArgTest)
{
    MockFoo mock;

    rapidjson::Document document;
    rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();

    rapidjson::Value object(rapidjson::kObjectType);
    object.AddMember("Math", "50", allocator);
    object.AddMember("Science", "70", allocator);
    object.AddMember("English", "50", allocator);
    object.AddMember("Social Science", "70", allocator);

    rapidjson::Value saveVal;

    ON_CALL(mock, foo).WillByDefault(SaveRapidJsonValueArg(&saveVal));

    mock.foo(object, 1);

    if (saveVal.HasMember("Math"))
        std::cout << saveVal["Math"].GetString() << "\n";
}
```

The execution crashes at the `HasMember()` call.

### Update2:

Thanks Chris Olsen again! Here's what I ended up doing.

```
ACTION_P2(SaveRapidJsonValueArg, valuePtr, doc)
{
    valuePtr->CopyFrom(arg1, doc->GetAllocator());
}

TEST(RapidJsonTests, SaveArgTest)
{
    ...
    ...

    ON_CALL(mock, foo).WillByDefault(SaveRapidJsonValueArg(&saveVal, &document));

    ...
    ...
}
```

Thanks again Chris!

Comment: Edited my answer after seeing your edit. Two problems: 1) `saveVal["Math"].HasMember("Math")` should be `saveVal.HasMember("Math")`, and 2) The document allocator needs to be captured in the custom action.

Comment: @ChrisOlsen Thanks for pointing (1) out. I've updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell where the problem is from the code shown. You should try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) whenever possible.

One problem you could be running into is that RapidJSON does not allow normal copying of `Value` objects. It uses move semantics instead. From the [RapidJSON Tutorial](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html):

> A very special decision during design of RapidJSON is that, assignment
>   of value does not copy the source value to destination value. Instead,
>   the value from source is moved to the destination. For example,
>
> ```
> Value a(123);
> Value b(456);
> b = a;         // a becomes a Null value, b becomes number 123.
> ```

To actually make a copy of a `Value` object, you can use the `Value::CopyFrom` method. A [custom action](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#writing-new-actions-quickly-quicknewactions) could be used to do this in gMock:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

using namespace ::testing;

class FooClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo(rapidjson::Value& element, int number) {}
};

class MockFoo : public FooClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, foo, (rapidjson::Value& element, int number));
};

struct CaptureFooValue
{
    void operator()(const rapidjson::Value &element, int) const
    {
        v.CopyFrom(element, d.GetAllocator(), true);
    }
    rapidjson::Value &v;
    rapidjson::Document &d;
};

TEST(RapidJsonTests, SaveArgTest)
{
    MockFoo mock;
    rapidjson::Document document;
    rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();

    rapidjson::Value object(rapidjson::kObjectType);
    object.AddMember("Math", "50", allocator);
    object.AddMember("Science", "70", allocator);
    object.AddMember("English", "50", allocator);
    object.AddMember("Social Science", "70", allocator);

    rapidjson::Value saveVal;

    ON_CALL(mock, foo).WillByDefault(CaptureFooValue{saveVal, document});

    mock.foo(object, 1);

    if (saveVal.HasMember("Math"))
        std::cout << saveVal["Math"].GetString() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I wasn't aware of the `ACTION_P ` macro with gmock. I tried it out with `argVal` being an object rather than a string. And when I try to check if `saveVal` has a member using `saveVal.HasMember("something")`, the execution crashes. Any idea?

Comment: @theNotSoPro Took another crack based on your edits. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for help! I saw what you did and altered my `ACTION_P` to handle it. Thanks for your time.